# Does simple form works with nested objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, simple-form

I have two forms **One** shows proper error notifications and the **Two** doesn`t. And I don`t know why.

**One:**
Announcement_form:

It has announcement variable, `announcement = @announcement`

```
<%= simple_form_for announcement do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :title, label: "Nazwa", placeholder: "Tytuł Posta", error: "Proszę podać tytuł" %>
  <%= f.input :message, label: "Treść", placeholder: "Treść Posta", error: "Post musi posiadać treść", as: :text, input_html: { 'rows' => 12 } %>
  <%= f.submit  "Dodaj Newsa ;)", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

with controller action:

```
  def create
    @announcement = Announcement.new(announcement_params)
    if @announcement.save
      flash[:success] = "Post został pomyślnie dodany"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

And **Two:**

Characteer form:

```
<article class="character_form ">
  <%= simple_form_for [@user, @user.characters.new] do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :name, label: "Imię", placeholder: "Imię postaci", error: "Proszę podać imię postaci" %>
    <%= f.input :clan, collection: CLAN_NAMES_ARRAY, label: "Klan:", include_blank: false  %>
    <%= f.input :family, label: "Rodzina:", include_blank: false %>
    <%= f.input :desc, label: "Opis Postaci:", placeholder: "Opisz swoją postać...", error: "Postać musi posiadać opis" %>
    <%= f.submit "Zapisz", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

  <% end %>
</article>
```

With action:

```
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @character = @user.characters.new(character_params)

    if @character.save
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Both are pretty standard stuff, the problem I have encountered, is that in first example, simple_form returns nice validation notifications, and in the second form it doesn't. The only difference I see between those two forms is that character object is an nested object (@user.character) and announcement is not. I have a presence validations for the both models.

**My question is:**

Does simple_form shows error_notifications for the nested obejcts ? (I think it should). If yes, what is wrong with my code that prevent`s them for the second form.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in both in my controller and form_partial

What helped in controller was, change:

`@character = @user.characters.new` to `@character = Character.new`

and in my form:

`<%= simple_form_for [@user, @user.characters.new] do |f| %>`

to

`<%= simple_form_for [@user, @character] do |f| %>`